# How can I give annotations to each subplot of distplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, jupyter-notebook, subplot

I'm trying to label each of my subplots as "positively skewed" or "negatively skewed" depending on the skewness shown by these distplots. I have used matplotlib and seaborn as packages involved. How can I annotate or label these graphs the following way ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18, 6))
sb.distplot(data['1_Yr_Return'], ax=ax[0], color='red')
sb.distplot(data['3_Yr_Return'], ax=ax[1], color='black')
sb.distplot(data['5_Yr_Return'], ax=ax[2], color='deepskyblue')
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHaoN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html?highlight=text#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text), or the slightly more versatile [`Axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,5))
ax[0].text(0.5,0.85,"Positively skewed")
```